# How to freeze first numbers in sequences between NaNs in Python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, nan

Is there a Pythonic way to, in a timeseries dataframe, by column, go down and pick the first number in a sequence, and then push it forward until the next NaN, and then take the next non-NaN number and push that one down until the next NaN, and so on (retaining the indices and NaNs).

For example, I would like to convert this dataframe:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[np.nan,1,3,5,7,np.nan,2,4,6,np.nan], 'B':[8,6,4,np.nan,np.nan,9,7,3,np.nan,3], 'C':[np.nan,np.nan,4,2,6,np.nan,1,5,2,8]})
```

```
     A    B    C
0  NaN  8.0  NaN
1  1.0  6.0  NaN
2  3.0  4.0  4.0
3  5.0  NaN  2.0
4  7.0  NaN  6.0
5  NaN  9.0  NaN
6  2.0  7.0  1.0
7  4.0  3.0  5.0
8  6.0  NaN  2.0
9  NaN  3.0  8.0
```

To this dataframe:

```
Result = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[np.nan,1,1,1,1,np.nan,2,2,2,np.nan], 'B':[8,8,8,np.nan,np.nan,9,9,9,np.nan,3], 'C':[np.nan,np.nan,4,4,4,np.nan,1,1,1,1]})
```

```
     A    B    C
0  NaN  8.0  NaN
1  1.0  8.0  NaN
2  1.0  8.0  4.0
3  1.0  NaN  4.0
4  1.0  NaN  4.0
5  NaN  9.0  NaN
6  2.0  9.0  1.0
7  2.0  9.0  1.0
8  2.0  NaN  1.0
9  NaN  3.0  1.0
```

I know I can use a loop to iterate down the columns to do this, but would appreciate some help on how to do it in a more efficient Pythonic way on a very large dataframe. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
# where DF is not NaN
mask = DF.notna()
Result = (DF.shift(-1)           # fill the original NaN's with their next value
            .mask(mask)          # replace all the original non-NaN with NaN
            .ffill()             # forward fill 
            .fillna(DF.iloc[0])  # starting of the the columns with a non-NaN
            .where(mask)         # replace the original NaN's back
         )
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C
0  NaN  8.0  NaN
1  1.0  8.0  NaN
2  1.0  8.0  4.0
3  1.0  NaN  4.0
4  1.0  NaN  4.0
5  NaN  9.0  NaN
6  2.0  9.0  1.0
7  2.0  9.0  1.0
8  2.0  NaN  1.0
9  NaN  3.0  1.0
```

Comment: Wow. That's really clever! Thank you so much @Quang Hoang.